# Android TextView is failing with null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-layout

Android TextView is failing with null pointer exception

and its failing at "disp.setText("0");"

inside the method "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {"

I tried most of the suggestions provided in net. Still could not resolve it.

Please need help....

My Layout: "fragment_main.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="num_Clicked"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ullas.Test1.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and My Activity is : "MainActivity.java"

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView disp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        disp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        disp.setText("0");


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `R.id.textView1` is not in `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: No, R.id.textView1 is in "fragment_main.xml"

even i tried changing the code to below, but still it didn't work

setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

Comment: Please refer to this post and see my answer 
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212490/add-onclick-listner-to-android/23215752#23215752**

Answer (score 2):

you tell your layout is "fragment_main.xml" and textview is in this xml.

in your code, you are setting a different layout xml:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
disp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

you must set the layout you want to use, in order to be able to reach your textview:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
disp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: Even after Changing to "setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);"
Its Still the same.

Comment: with the code you provided it can't be wrong. 
project / clean and build and then run again please

Comment: After Clean and Build, Null pointer Exception was solved.

Now i'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c"

Comment: it is a problem about your fragment. may be you are setting it in a wrong place? you need to give more details.

Comment: What all information you need, OR Can you provide me your mail id i can send you the entire project to you.

Comment: I need at least your fragments and how do you call them from your fragmentactivity.

Comment: Hello Sir SC, i have posted the complete code below. Please do let me know in case if you need any other information on the same.

Answer (score 0):

The view textView1 is not found in the layout file loaded. View hierarchy should be created before getting view from the layout.

Comment: <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"

is present in the code which i have posted above in "fragment_main.xml". 

any changes to be done to that. 

Please explain in detail..

Answer (score 0):

Complete "MainActivity.java" is below

---

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView disp;
        disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        disp.setText("0");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

---

and Below is the Complete "fragment_main.xml"

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Below is the "activity_main.xml"

---

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

---

and ONE MORE THING , WHEN I CREATE A NEW PROJECT BY DEFAULT IT WILL GIVE ME THIS "Fragment_main.xml"