# Add Onclick listner to android

Tags: android

I am using Adt version 22.0.

I added an oclick listener to a button inside onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter=0;
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }



}
```

When I add onclick listener like above Application crashes.

This is my log Cat error.

```
04-22 01:08:36.900: I/Choreographer(836): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 01:08:37.460: D/gralloc_goldfish(836): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-22 02:27:35.010: D/AndroidRuntime(1183): Shutting down VM
04-22 02:27:35.010: W/dalvikvm(1183): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9fba8)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Process: com.example.androidtest, PID: 1183
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtest/com.example.androidtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.example.androidtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     ... 11 more
```

Could not I add onclick listener inside oncreate method
Please help with this

LogCat for tushar narang's answer

```
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Process: com.example.androidtest, PID: 1183
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtest/com.example.androidtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.example.androidtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-22 02:27:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     ... 11 more
```

This is the main fest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.androidtest" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LayoutFile

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.androidtest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Total is 0"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add one"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bSub" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Substract one"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should check your `Buttons` belong to `activity_main.xml` layout.

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: Can you check what is line number 36 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: Also change that line to - `add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

Comment: Line no 36 is }); code

Comment: It is the default one.I did not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this ,make sure you edit the names for buttons or textview

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
    private TextView txtSensor ;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        txtSensor = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSensor);
        txtSensor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
        return rootView;
    }
```

If this doesn't work please post your code

Answer (score 0):

```
protected class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 

Button add,sub;
 TextView display;
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter=0;
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


      public void onClick(View v) 

          {

                if (v == add)

                      {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "add pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       }

                           if (v == sub)

                         {


Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sub pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }
                      }




    }
```

Comment: I added the logcat to the question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the button IDs in activity_main are correct?

```
add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Can you put a breakpoint in your code and check if 'add' is getting populated with the correct view?

Comment: Yes. Program only crashes if only add onclick event

Comment: I tried your code as it is, and it is working fine for me.  Can you please check if you are loading the correct layout file?

Answer (score 0):

i guess buttons & textviews are in your fragment_main.xml & you are referencing them through activity_main.xml
Try referencing them in OncreateView method in placeholder fragment

Comment: Text views are in  fragment_main.xml How can I refer them

Comment: place this in placeholder's oncreateview method  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_container, false);
txtSensor = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSensor);

Answer (score 0):

YOU USE THIS CODE

> Button add; add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
>   add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>     }
> });
> ```

or you use

> class Myclass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
>
> Button add;
>
> ```
>    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
>     add.setOnClickListener(this);
> ```
>
> } public void onClick(View v)
>
> ```
>       {
> Switch(v.getId()){
> Case:R.id.bAdd{
> ////Write your code
> ```
>
> break;  }
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: this code use inside oncreate if you get error than write new View.OnClickListener() more http://www.androidpanna.com/functionality/change-activity-with-intent-by-clicking-a-button-android-development