# Unfortunately <app> has stopped

Tags: android

I am a newbie to java and android app development. I am trying to develop a small android app to take a text from the user and on the click of a button,convert it to speech. I got no errors in the code. But when I run it it shows 'unfortunately app has stopped".
Can I get some help?

```
package com.daya.wetalk;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener{

private int TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT=1;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private EditText edit;
private ImageButton b;

String incomingmessage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts= new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);

   edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mEdit);
   b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mButton);

   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){

    incomingmessage=edit.getText().toString();

    if (incomingmessage != null){
        speakOut(incomingmessage);
    }
       }
   });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

   private void speakOut(String msg){
        String text = msg.toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if (tts != null){
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
     if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        }else{
            speakOut(incomingmessage);
        }

        }else{
            Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed!");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the logcat log :

```
04-28 05:41:47.455: I/TextToSpeech(17110): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
04-28 05:41:47.465: W/dalvikvm(17110): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418f22a0)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daya.wetalk/com.daya.wetalk.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at com.daya.wetalk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
04-28 05:41:47.465: E/AndroidRuntime(17110):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Do you use eclipse or android studio? Please run the app while LogCat is shown, this way you will find the Exception that occurs so we can help you.

Comment: Refer to this link.This may help you [http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/)

Comment: nice annotation in top on the class

Comment: You have to look at the logs to know where the problem come from (and copy paste the stack trace here, for us to help). In Eclipse, you have a LogCat view especially for that.

Comment: @SSK I'm not sure this is relevant for now. The OP has an exception and wants to know his current problem.

Comment: Your problem is on line 40 of MainActivity.java. What is on that line?

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have declared the editText & button in activity xml or fragment xml. if so do the required changes.

ok so thats where you went wrong. you have your ui components in fragment and you are initialising them in activity .

Place this

```
tts= new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);

   edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mEdit);
   b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mButton);

   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){

    incomingmessage=edit.getText().toString();

    if (incomingmessage != null){
        speakOut(incomingmessage);
    }
       }
   });
```

inside oncreate of placeholder fragment

check my answer here if you are still not clear  [Add Onclick listner to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212490/add-onclick-listner-to-android/23215752#23215752)

declare this variables as global variables inside placeholder class

```
private int TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT=1;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private EditText edit;
private ImageButton b;
String incomingmessage;
```

Comment: I have declared them in fragment xml

Comment: thank you ....'The constructor TextToSpeech(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener) is undefined'   ...this is the only error now